# Renewal fails but license remains active, and a new recurring is made

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce, Commerce License, and Commerce License Billing.

Something unexpected is happening.

1. When an order tries to renew but fails (due to a card issue): the
   order that had been in the system with a status='recurring_open' is
   updated to have a status = 'cardonfile_payment_error_hard_decline'.
2. The license is still active
3. A new order is made. It has the status 'recurring_open'. It has an active billing cycle.

My Thoughts

Concerning #1 - This seems expected, though I expected the declined status to be on a new order and not the previously existing order. I am not sure if that is correct.

Concerning #2 - It seems to me a license should be canceled in this situation but I am not sure how this is intended to work. I see in the commerce_license.module a hook_commerce_order_update implementation but it only cancels licenses when an order status = 'cancelled' and not when status = 'cardonfile_payment_error_hard_decline'. What is intended?

Concerning #3 -  I think this could be a symptom on #2. Maybe if the license had been cancelled a new recurring order would not be made? BUT because of #3 this order will attempt to renew again at the end of the new billing cycle, starting this issue all over again.

I know this is a specific issue. Any help is appreciated.

It would be nice to know what is suppose to happen when a renewal is declined.

** Update **
I have found that in commerce_license_billing.module on line 340 is where the additional recurring order is being created. Reviewing this code, I see nothing that would stop this regardless if the renewal failed.

To test, I added the patch below (above Line 340 on Line 322). This code completes the renewal process immediately if the order did not complete. This prevents the additional recurring order from being made. Additionally it prevents the new billing cycle from being made and prevents the license from being extended. All good things IMO.

The only thing it doesn't do is revoke the license. That is okay for my use case. With a couple of more lines of code, the licenses could be revoked too.

My main question is still:
Am I creating new functionality for my use case because Commerce License Billing does not deal with card declines?
OR
Is there something wrong with how my install is behaving and this patch should not be needed?

```
*** commerce_license_billing.module 2016-01-12 16:26:46.000000000 -0800
--- commerce_license_billing_patched.module 2016-01-12 16:25:28.000000000 -0800
***************
*** 311,316 ****
--- 311,325 ----
    }
    $order = $billing_cycle->getOrder();

+   //If the order did not renew successfully do not create a new recurring order. 
+   if ($order->status!='completed') {
+     // The billing cycle has been deleted in the meantime. Nothing more to do.
+     return array(
+       'status' => ADVANCEDQUEUE_STATUS_FAILURE,
+       'result' => 'Order had not renewed successfully.',
+     );
+   }
+ 
    $licenses = commerce_license_billing_get_recurring_order_licenses($order);
    foreach ($licenses as $license) {
      // Apply scheduled changes.
```

Just providing my updates to help the conversation. :)

Comment: Same issue here. Would be nice to hear from DC developers.

Comment: There was a response from the community on drupal.org. There is a separate module you should use to handle this.
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_dunning

More discussion:
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing/issues/2649108